# Unable to access Public properties of usercontrol from aspx in vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have googled about it and saw already the post of the other users with the same problem.
All of the post have the same solution. I followed all the steps and codes but I still can't solve the problem. Still I'm not able to access the declared properties.

I'm new to Vb.net, Pardon if it is a stupid question.

Here is the code for my usercontrol

```
Public Class CustomUserControls
Dim msg As String
Dim innerMsg As String
Dim modal As Boolean

Public Property SetMessage() As String
    Get
        Return msg
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        msg = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SetInnerMsg() As String
    Get
        Return innerMsg
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        innerMsg = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PopUpModal() As Boolean
    Get
        Return modal
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        modal = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

this is my usercontrol design code:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ShowMessageControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="UserControls_ShowMessageControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="DummyForMessagebox" style="display:none;" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalShowMessage" runat="server" TargetControlID="DummyForMessagebox">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlShowMessage">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>`enter code here`
            <h5>Header</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" CssClass="text-info"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblInnerMessage"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

and in my aspx file

```
<uc1:ShowMessageControl runat="server" ID="ShowMessageControl" />
```

and what i want when im trying to access my usercontrol properties

```
ShowMessageControl.MustApperProperty
```

but when i showmessagecontrol and then dot.. there is no declared properties appearing

Comment: How are you trying to access said properties?

Comment: im expecting something like this..
ShowMessageControl.myproperty.. but no property i declared is comming out

Comment: Please show us the actual code that you're trying to use to access the properties. Edit it into your question. And what is `ShowMessageControl`?

Comment: i already edited my post sir. sorry for the previous post

Comment: The code you originally shared is for `CustomUserControls`. Now you are showing us `ShowMessageControl`. Are the two related? Does one inherit from the other? I also don't see `MustApperProperty` declared in your code. And btw you really don't need to call me (or anyone on StackOverflow) *sir*...

Comment: the mustappearproperty is for explanation purpose only..
if my code works it should appear like this ShowMessageControl.SetMessage

Comment: Ok. Could you now replace the class definition of CustomUserControls with the one of your actual class: ShowMessageControl? Also: maybe there is just InteliSense not working. Have you tried compiling your code?

Comment: that is the actual class.. yes i already compiled the code but still not working.

Comment: Your class with the properties is `CustomUserControls`. The control you are trying to use is `ShowMessageControl`. They are different.

Comment: wew!!! thank you so much.. i did not know that the class and the name of the usercontrol should be the same.. thanks a lot.... ur my hero..